# Set pagename to _trackEvent in ga.js

Tags: google-analytics

Using the new analytics.js, according to the documentation it is possible to do something like this:

`ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {'page': '/my-new-page'});`

I cannot upgrade to analytics.js (I don't control this), so, is there a way of setting the page name using the old ga.js `_trackEvent()` method?

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is undocumented override capabilities.

```
_gaq.push(['_set', 'page', '/new-url.html']);
_gaq.push(['_set', 'title', 'New Super Cool Title']);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','category','action','label']);
```

This may help ensure that you aren't providing two _trackPageview and skewing your traffic numbers.

Comment: This just saved my bacon. I needed to track a pageView for content that opens in a hidden div (i.e. not a real page), and just using _trackPageview with the URL gave me hits with a variety of titles depending on which page the user opened the hidden content. This allowed me to consolidate all the hits under the same title.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can just pass a virtual pageview into an event using ga.js. The reason this works in analytics.js is because Google rewrote Google Analytics from the ground-up. However, you could use [One Push, Multiple Commands](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/?hl=en#MultipleCommands).

```
_gaq.push(
['_trackPageview','/my-new-page'],
['_trackEvent','category','action','label']
);
```

Comment: Note that if you're wanting to associate the event with my-new-page (as it would in the analytics.js snippet in the question), you'll need to fire the _trackPageview first. Otherwise the event would show up on the original _trackPageview request in the Event Pages report.

Comment: Will this skew my traffic results though?  Meaning, by calling another _trackPageview, it is going to double my traffic for that particular url.. no?

Comment: Anytime you add a virtual pageview i.e. another _trackPageview call, it will add to your total pageview count. There is more documentation on google about when you should use [virtual pageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples#VirtualPageviews).